# Firefox: Some Websites are not shown correctly?

Tags: firefox

Some websites, including stackoverflow.com and superuser.com look like this in Firefox:

[image]

This is what I see on the console:

[image]

I am using Firefox Quantum 61.0.2

I noticed that the website works in Chrome. I also tried to open the websites on an other device, and there it the website was correctly shown in Firefox. Therefore I think it must be related to my laptop, but what could the issue be? Everything was still working fine yesterday in Firefox.

Comment: Ad-blocker or other extensions installed? Any "internet security" suite running? Looks like some kind of script or css blocking is going on.

Comment: @Mokubai yes its the adblocker!!! Thank you so muich!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hopefully canonical answer...

Missing scripts and pages lacking formatting is often a sign of overzealous ad-blocker or internet security engines.

If the problem is limited to one particular browser then as a first step you should look for an ad-blocker in your browser extensions.

In Firefox: Click on the "menu" button and select "Add-ons" and then go to the Extensions tab.

In Chrome: Click the "menu" button, then under "more tools" select "Extensions".

<sub>todo: add Edge, IE and Opera</sub>

Look for extensions such as "Adblock", "UBlock" or similar.

As a test you should disable extensions and reload the faulty webpage to see if the blocking was caused by the extension in question.

It may be that you have accidentally added a rule which has resulted in elements being blocked from the page so if disabling the ad-blocker fixes the issue then you should go into the options for the extension (from the browser extensions page) and check for any "custom" or "user defined" rules and clear them out if necessary.

If there is no custom rules blocking the elements then you may have a faulty ad-blocker or rule set supplied to you in which case your only options are to change ad-blocker or wait for it to be updated.

Alternatively many Internet security suites such as McAffee, Kaspersky or Norton may be filtering webpages. For sites that you have recently visited it may initially appear to affect only one browser, but the problem may "suddenly" migrate to both.

In this case you will need to check the settings for the suite in question to disable internet filtering, script  blocking and other such features.